# Identity type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

Can the identity type be expressed in Typescript?

I know that the identity function can be type as

```js
type IdentFunc = <T>(input: T) => T
```

Since all generics are on the right side of the type, they are inferred from the source code. So, the type can be used cleanly

```js
const f: IdentFunc = x => x;
const a = f(4)
   // ^? const a: 4
```

However, if I try to write down the identity type, the best I can come up with is

```js
type Ident<T> = T
```

However, `T` in this case is not inferred and must be supplied explicitly. The following code gives an error.

```js
const x: Ident = 4;
```

This can be solved using the more verbose

```js
const x: Ident<typeof 4> = 4;
```

which duplicates information I'd like to be inferred.

My question is, is there a way to declare the identity type? More generally, is there a way to declare a type with generics parameters that are inferred from the right side of a type assignment?

Comment: For generic *types*, there is no mechanism to infer the type parameters.  Such inference only happens when calling a generic *function*, so the best you can do here is `const x = f(4)`... that is, use a helper function to simulate generic type argument inference.  See the linked q/a for more information.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is currently no way in TypeScript to declare a type with generic parameters that are inferred from the right side of a type assignment in the way you described for direct type annotations. The inference works in the context of functions but not for standalone type annotations.

Your approach with const x: Ident<typeof 4> = 4; is the correct and necessary way to use such generic types outside of function contexts.

Comment: That's too bad :-(. Do you know if there's an open bug filed for this issue?

Comment: It’s not a bug; at worst it’s a missing feature